# XPath: axe following-sibling not accurate enough

Tags: xpath

I navigate inside EDIFACT messages (bad) enveloped into XML messages, using standard XPath version 2.0 axes. Below is a short extract:

```
<Loop type="RFF">
    <RepeatingSegment type="RFF">
        <Segment type="RFF" name="REFERENCE">
            <Element type="1153" name="Reference qualifier" value="Order number (purchase)">ON</Element>
            <Element type="1154" name="Reference number">0104772302</Element>
        </Segment>
        <Segment type="RFF" name="REFERENCE">
            <Element type="1153" name="Reference qualifier" value="Delivery note number">DQ</Element>
            <Element type="1154" name="Reference number">052620228</Element>
        </Segment>
    </RepeatingSegment>
    <RepeatingSegment type="DTM">
        <Segment type="DTM" name="DATE/TIME/PERIOD">
            <Element type="2005" name="Date/time/period qualifier" value="Reference date/time">171</Element>
            <Element type="2380" name="Date/time/period">20180207</Element>
            <Element type="2379" name="Date/time/period format qualifier" value="CCYYMMDD">102</Element>
        </Segment>
    </RepeatingSegment>
</Loop>
```

The standard XPath axe “following-sibling”, even forced with [1], returns the unique date (DTM) for the first reference (RFF), but this date belongs to the second reference (RFF)…

```
/Loop[@type='RFF']/RepeatingSegment[@type='RFF']/Segment[@type='RFF']/Element[@type=1153 and text()='ON']/../../following-sibling::RepeatingSegment[@type='DTM'][1]/Segment[@type='DTM']/Element[@type=2380]
```

returns “20180207”. So, I am looking for a trick that could return the “Siamese” date (or nothing, if this date does not exist, as into the above extract).

The term « Siamese » is not clear: I am now using the term “couple”. Ideally, if the XML message was completed, they should be two couples of Reference-Date, unfortunately into different RepeatingSegment groups (it is why I mentioned first that the EDIFACT message is bad enveloped, by a legacy system).

When there are two different Dates for each Reference, as the second extract below, the following-sibling axe is fine to pick them after each Reference:

```
<Loop type="RFF">
    <RepeatingSegment type="RFF">
        <Segment name="REFERENCE" type="RFF">
            <Element name="Reference qualifier" type="1153" value="Order number (purchase)">ON</Element>
            <Element name="Reference number" type="1154">0CDE922802</Element>
        </Segment>
    </RepeatingSegment>
    <RepeatingSegment type="DTM">
        <Segment name="DATE/TIME/PERIOD" type="DTM">
            <Element name="Date/time/period qualifier" type="2005" value="Reference date/time">171</Element>
            <Element name="Date/time/period" type="2380">20170619</Element>
            <Element name="Date/time/period format qualifier" type="2379" value="CCYYMMDD">102</Element>
        </Segment>
    </RepeatingSegment>
    <RepeatingSegment type="RFF">
        <Segment name="REFERENCE" type="RFF">
            <Element name="Reference qualifier" type="1153" value="Delivery note number">DQ</Element>
            <Element name="Reference number" type="1154">00000004</Element>
        </Segment>
    </RepeatingSegment>
    <RepeatingSegment type="DTM">
        <Segment name="DATE/TIME/PERIOD" type="DTM">
            <Element name="Date/time/period qualifier" type="2005" value="Reference date/time">171</Element>
            <Element name="Date/time/period" type="2380">20180726</Element>
            <Element name="Date/time/period format qualifier" type="2379" value="CCYYMMDD">102</Element>
        </Segment>
    </RepeatingSegment>
</Loop>
```

But when the first Date is missing, as into the first extract above, the following-sibling axe picks the Date of the second reference (which is well the first occurrence of a Date, as the first date is missing). So, yes, the above XPath expression is working normally.

It is why I am looking for another XPath expression, which would return nothing (empty string), instead of the first following “bad” Date. In fact, a kind of “following-adjacent-sibling” axe, which does not exist yet into XPath, should be useful.

Comment: The output `20180207` is exactly what your XPath should return. Can you explain what you expect to get?

Comment: I'm don't understand what you mean by the "Siamese" date. Your XPath expression is clearly doing exactly what it should. It's not clear (a) why you expected it to do something different, or (b) what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks Andersson and Michael for your questions. I have just edited my post above with additional information.

Comment: Adjacent-sibling is better than "Siamese".